# Topology topics for Profinite Groups

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation, profinite-groups

I want to start studying Profinite Groups, but I have not taken a forma coure on Topology. I have studied: continuity, open, closed, compact, connected. I'd like to know what topics I still need to learn to study Profinite Groups. If possible, I would like some recommendation of Topology books that cover the necessary topics.

Comment: Did you study these topics for metric spaces (e.g. $\mathbb R$)? Or do you know the general definition?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group) for a good survey of what you need: discrete topology, inverse limit, Krull topology etc. I would recommend the topology book by Dugundji. By the way, [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662040973) on profinite groups also covers the topology you need.

Comment: @TrevorGunn, the general definition (for topological spaces).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you! I'll read your recommendation.